# How do I make sure a bluetooth app will only connect to the original peripheral?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

My current project is a simple bicycle odometer app using a bluetooth speed sensor. 
I have used 'Wahoo', Xoss', 'CycPlus' sensors (peripheral) for testing. 
App is intended for ios - iPhones.

The app runs well - using CoreBluetooth - simplified flow

- initialize central manager
- scan for peripherals with services
- using did discover peripheral > connect to peripheral
- using did connect peripheral > discover services
- using did discover services > discover characteristics
- using did discover characteristics > set notifying to yes for peripheral
- using did update value for characteristic >  extract my data and calculate mileage

All works well - as long as the bicycle keeps moving. But when the peripheral (bt sensor) stops broadcasting during a several minute rest period, the peripheral disconnects  - as it should.

The problem is that if another bluetooth equipped bicycle starts up in the vicinity, the app will attempt to connect to that other peripheral.

How can I -

1. Make sure to reconnect only to the original peripheral.

or

2. Make sure I never disconnect from the original peripheral.

Thanks

JDay

Comment: You shouldn't scan each time. Provide a setup screen where you scan and show available peripherals for the user to select one. Store its `identifier` and use that to connect to your target peripheral. Use `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers` to get the peripheral on a subsequent run. During a run if the peripheral disconnects just call `connect` straight away

Answer (score 0):

Paulw11

My apologies for posting comment as an answer - too much to say.

Thanks for the suggestions. I have used your key items, and flavored a bit for my unmentioned specifics. I believe I have a working solution based on your guidance.

Rather than `retrievePeripheralWithIdentifiers`, I just get and save the CBUUID on first connect.

Then when connecting, I filter the incoming peripherals to match the original CBUUID.

I beleieve I do need to use scan, rather than just connect, because I do not know when the rider
will begin moving again. I don't want to ask the rider to press a button. I need to keep scanning in order to detect his motion.

Here's the jist of my added code:

```
...in implementation
bool preferredPeripheralExists = false;

...in peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService
NSString *founduuid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [peripheral.identifier  UUIDString]] ;
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:founduuid forKey:@"rememberFoundUUID"];
[prefs synchronize];
preferredPeripheralExists = true ;

 ... in didDiscoverPeripheral   
NSString *newuuid     = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [peripheral.identifier  UUIDString]] ;
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *olduuid     = [prefs objectForKey:@"rememberFoundUUID"]  ;

if ((!preferredPeripheralExists) || (preferredPeripheralExists && [newuuid isEqualToString:olduuid])){  
  if (self.discoveredPeripheral != peripheral) {
     self.discoveredPeripheral = peripheral;
     [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
  } // if self
}   // if !preferred
```

With regard to your comment about a setup screen, and user selection of the peripheral -

My flow scheme is based on the sample xcode project on the apple developer site. This makes no mention of a setup interface. Also the Ray Wenderlich bluetooth heart monitor project does not include ability for user to select a device.

Is it considered poor practice to not include a device selection screen?

Thanks

J.Day